# FFMPEG/libav: how to match a linux lib version to a source code commit

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, shared-libraries

I'm having trouble using a libav function, so I thought I'd dig into the source and see why it's not doing what I expect.

I want to checkout the source version used on my system, obviously, but I don't know how to match these.

```
$ ldd my_application | grep avformat
libavformat.so.56 => /usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.56 (0x00007f629ef8f000)
```

How can I find out the git tag that was used to build version 56 of the shared lib?

Answer (score 1):

Each part of `libav*` includes a header named `version.h`. You can easily find the version number in that file. For example, at the beginning (after the macro guard and other includes) of `ffmpeg/libavcodec/version.h`:

```
#define LIBAVFORMAT_VERSION_MAJOR  57
#define LIBAVFORMAT_VERSION_MINOR  46
#define LIBAVFORMAT_VERSION_MICRO 101
```

The shared object file of this version should be `libavformat.so.57.46.101`.

If you can be sure the header files you're using is the same version with `.so` files, just check them.

However, if not, I don't think there is an easy way to find the corresponding git tag to the lib file. Maybe you have to checkout several versions. Btw, `libavformat` major version 56 starts from ffmpeg version 2.4.x to 2.8.x, which is a quite large range.

Comment: I used `gitk` and its search abilities to find `LIBAVFORMAT_VERSION_MAJOR 56`. The hard thing is that I have `libavformat.so.56` installed, with no minor nor micro number.

Comment: @Gauthier This is troublesome then. Anyway, have you found the header files? What's your application include path?   If ffmpeg installed by `apt-get` or other package managers, `/usr/include/libav*` is the most likely place to find them.